# Want to Get Value for More than one Matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In my program i have considered one matrix and getting the output for one matrix. But i want to get output for multiple number of matrix. Example:
My Program from where i am getting my output for D is below. In the below program i have only one value for the parameter "error". But i want to get it for 20 values for this parameter. Here in this case error = 0.2, but i want to get the value of D for error =[.21 .22 .23 .24 .25 .26 .27 ... upto 20 values]

I know this is not a big problem for Matlab experts. Can you suggest in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you can simply loop over the possible values of `error`, and store the respective `D` for each one of them.

```
 N=30;
C = zeros(N , N);
plc = zeros(1, N) ;
rec1_Wopt = zeros(1, length(N)) ;
rec2_Wopt = zeros(1, length(N)) ;
ap1_Wopt = zeros(1, length(N));
ap2_Wopt = zeros(1, length(N));

C(1:N,1:N) = eye(N) ;
count = 1; %%%% ADJUSTED
for error=0.2:0.01:0.39; %%%% ADJUSTED

for Trial = 1 ;
R=C;
for i=1:N
   if(rand < error )
    R(i,:) = 0;
  end
end



RecP=zeros(1,N) ;
  for j = 1 : N
    CpD = max( C(j,:)-RecP, 0) ; 
    if( sum(CpD) == 1) 
      plc(j) = plc(j) + 1;
    end 
    RpD = max( R(j,:)-RecP, 0) ; 
    if( sum(RpD) == 1)  
      [MaxValue Idx] = max(RpD) ;
      RecP(Idx) = 1 ;
    end
  end
  rec2_Wopt(1) = rec2_Wopt(1) + sum(RecP) ;
  if( sum(RecP) == N )
    ap2_Wopt(1) = ap2_Wopt(1) + 1;
  end
end


D(count,:) =rec2_Wopt / Trial ; %%%% ADJUSTED
count = count+1;  %%%% ADJUSTED
end  %%%% ADJUSTED
```

I marked the adjusted lines as such.

If there is a problem with storing the result to `D`, try using a cell array, for example

```
D(count) ={rec2_Wopt / Trial}
```

Comment: thank you for the adjustment. But when it is counting then the previous D value is adding up with the next one. I want to collect it speperately and also how to store the values of D if i want to increase the trial? Like i want to get the values of Trial =10? Any suggestion?

Comment: @user2663126 Not sure what the problem is, this is what I had in mind: `count = 1; D = [];for error = 2.2:0.01:2.39, D(count,:)=rand(3,1);count = count+1;end` If you now want to extract the seventh result for example, you can do: `D(7,:)`

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin your code is working fine but my point is that, for the second value of p, i am getting the combined output of two D,(like if the previous value of D is 30 then for second p i am getting the next D value as the summation of two D which is like 30+29=59 and for third p again summation of three D = 30+29+28 like this). But i want to get all the D values separate not as added values. Any suggestion?